# diffrence between .vimrc and .gvimrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I have vim and gvim on my ubuntu.
I know the vim configuration file  **~/.vimrc** and the gvim configuration file  **~/.gvimrc**.
Sometimes I write into these files to change the configuration of vim/gvim.
**But,**

1. How do these two files work exactly ?

2. Why when I modify the file **~/.vimrc** but it works **also for gvim**? So what is the point of have two configuration files? Just one file --> **~/.vimrc** can already do the job, can't it?

Comment: your question has already been answered: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/471/why-do-i-need-both-a-vimrc-and-a-gvimrc

Comment: @erroia I already read this answer before posting my question, but because of my English level, I did not really get it. The answer below that I accepted is clear and simple enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`:help gvimrc`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#gvimrc):

> The `gvimrc` file is where GUI-specific startup commands should be
>   placed.  It is always sourced after the [`vimrc`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#vimrc) file.
>
> You can use the gvimrc files to set up your own customized menus (see
>   [`:menu`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#%3Amenu)) and initialize other things that you may want to set up
>   differently from the terminal version.